# Jquery open multiple tabs works in FF but not chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code works fine in Firefox but not in chrome (In chrome it only opens the first item)
It's supposed to open all checked links in a new tab. Any suggestions?

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery("#open_in_new_tab").click(function(){
          jQuery("#sales_order_grid_table input:checked").each(function(index){
           var $href=jQuery(this).parent().parent().attr("title");
            window.open($href);
      });
         });
          });
```

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome.. Can you create a Fiddle?

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Everglades/tgp206ey/
First check some items and then click the button "Markierte Öffnen" oin the top of the grid

Comment: Yeah, that still works fine for me in Chrome.

Comment: It opens multiple tabs? Um it only opens one for me in Chrome.
I tested it on 2 different PC's

Comment: Fixed it... Chrome blocked the popups.. Damn Thanks for the hint :)